# How to prevent VS Code for C# to Auto generate overrides for Object class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

In VS Code by pressing `ctrl+.` it gives the option to generate overrides for the subclass.

However, it also generates overrides inherited from Object class.

Does anyone know how to prevent that?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not clear exactly what you want.  Do you want to suppress the default methods inherited from the Object class?  If so, this is not possible.   BTW:  This is not VS behaviour, but that of the .Net Framework (Java and other languages also work the same way).

Comment: For example, I have an abstract class with two abstract methods. When I want to implement these two in a concrete class, by hitting the mentioned shortcut, I get not only those two abstract methods, but some methods from the "Object" class.
Is there anyway to change this behavior?